# Selenium - org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver cannot be cast to com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium

Tags: java, api, google-chrome, apache-flex, selenium

I'm using [flex-ui-selenium](https://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/) to automate my flex application, which adds 2 numbers and displays the result in an alert box.

Below is my selenium code:

```
package com.selenium.testcases;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.FlexUISelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class FlashSeleniumtest {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\dev\\HydFramework\\Hyd\\HybridFrameWork\\jarsForAnt\\chromedriver.exe");
            String BASE_URL = "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0\\webapps\\FlexDemo\\SeleniumTest-debug\\SeleniumTest.html";
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            //FlashObjectWebDriver driver1  = new FlashObjectWebDriver((FlashObjectWebDriver) driver,"SeleniumTest");
            driver.get(BASE_URL);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            FlexUISelenium flexUITester;
            flexUITester = new FlexUISelenium((Selenium) driver, "SeleniumTest");
            flexUITester.type("100").at("first");
            flexUITester.type("200").at("second");
            flexUITester.click("Sum");
        }
        }
```

When I execute this code, I get the following exception:

"org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver cannot be cast to com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium". 
Please help.

Comment: U should import "org.openqa.selenium.Selenium" instead of "com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium".

Comment: @SarithaG I just imported it. But it says that the import can not be resolved...

Comment: You have download selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar file and add this jar file to your project as a build path.

Comment: It ain't working for me, even after adding 'selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar' in my project. Some other issue is there it seems...